# Ruby on Rails - External Image Url to Base64

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

is there anyway in Ruby on Rails to convert the image hosted in an image url (https://meo-fb-natal-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/participations/cropped/56658c5de2fc7116340000c0/635769180217506883-GD5A9264.jpg?1449495643) to Base64?

I've tried tons of things but none of them seem to work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What exactly is not working?

Here is an example:

```
$> irb
>> require 'open-uri'
>> img = open("https://meo-fb-natal-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/participations/cropped/56658c5de2fc7116340000c0/635769180217506883-GD5A9264.jpg?1449495643")
# img variable is a tempfile with image
>> require 'base64'
>> Base64.encode64(img.read)
=> "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/2wBDAAYEBQYFBAYGBQYHBwYIChAKCgkJ\nChQODwwQFxQYGBcUFhYaHSUfGhsjHBYWICwgIyYnKSopGR8tMC0oMCUoKSj/\n2wBDAQcHBwoIChMKChMoGhYaKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgo\nKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCj/wAARCAFTAoYDASIAAhEBAxEB/8QA\nHAAAAAcBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQIDBAUGBwAI/8QAShAAAgEDAgQEAwUGB..."
```

Comment: maybe im wrong, but those new lines (\n) aren't supposed to be there... if i put the jpg metatag in the begining it doesnt open in the browser...

Comment: use [`Base64.strict_encode64()`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html#method-i-strict_encode64) - *No line feeds are added.*

Comment: thank you sir, you really helped that was the click i needed! now i only have the put the metatag and its done but that i can do alone, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
url = "https://meo-fb-natal-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/participations/cropped/56658c5de2fc7116340000c0/635769180217506883-GD5A9264.jpg?1449495643"
ActiveSupport::Base64.encode64(open(url) { |io| io.read })
```